# Possible bug when parsing properties with goal "regex-property" of build-helper-maven-plugin?

Tags: maven

The requirement is that I have to parse a system property with regex in order to remove the dot from the value.

Execution example is: mvn install -Dsomeversion=1.3

pom.xml configuration is:

```xml
<plugin>
 <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
 <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
 <version>1.8</version>
 <executions>
  <execution>
   <id>regex-property</id>
   <goals>
    <goal>regex-property</goal>
   </goals>
   <configuration>
    <name>someversion.parsed</name>
    <value>$\{someversion}</value>
    <regex>(.*)[\._](.*)</regex>
    <replacement>$1$2</replacement>
    <failIfNoMatch>false</failIfNoMatch>
   </configuration>
  </execution>
 </executions>
</plugin>
```

Based on the plugin's documentation, the backslash must be there after the dollar sign in `<value>`

The issues are:

1. When the backslash is there, the system property is not parsed
2. If I remove the backslash:
   a) system property is parsed successfully
   b) if execute "mvn install" I am getting the error that the parameter 'value' is
      missing or incorrect, despite the fact that I have configured `<failIfNoMatch>false</failIfNoMatch>`

Any feedback would be highly appreciated

Thank you in advance

Comment: Note that you don't need to escape the dot in `[\._]` -- being inside of a character class already removes its special meaning.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

after some tests, I came to following conclusion:

- didn't see the documentation stating that '\' should follow '$' sign
  (maybe you can point me to it), so I removed it :), anyway escaping usually achieved by - '\' is relevant for next rather than previous character, as far as I know
- for the errror you see for `mvn install` is value of the config
  property `<failIfNoMatch>` irrelevant

The `<failIfNoMatch>` decides, should I fail if the system property is there but is not in the expected format? It doens't cover the case that property is not there at all. However for this purpose, in maven exist so called profiles, these can be activated in a different ways, one of them is system property presence.

So the following does the job for me:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0       http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>sample</groupId>
    <artifactId>sample</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <activation>
                <property>
                    <name>someversion</name>
                </property>
            </activation>

            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                        <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>1.8</version>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>regex-property</id>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>regex-property</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <configuration>
                                    <name>someversion.parsed</name>
                                    <value>${someversion}</value>
                                    <regex>(.*)[\._](.*)</regex>
                                    <!-- <regex>notmatched</regex>-->
                                    <replacement>$1$2</replacement>
                                    <failIfNoMatch>false</failIfNoMatch>
                                    <!--<failIfNoMatch>true</failIfNoMatch>-->
                                </configuration>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>1.7</version>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <phase>validate</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>run</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <configuration>
                                    <tasks>
                                        <echo>******** Displaying value of property ********</echo>
                                        <echo>${someversion.parsed}</echo>
                                    </tasks>
                                </configuration>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
    </profiles>


</project>
```

Please note that `maven-antrun-plugin` is there just to show debugging output.

Now some tests:

```
mvn install -Dsomeversion=1.3
...
main:
     [echo] ******** Displaying value of property ********
     [echo] 13
[INFO] Executed tasks
...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESSFUL
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
...
```

For no system property version:

```
mvn install
...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESSFUL
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
...
```

Without having special profile stuff in my pom.xml I'd get following output:

```
mvn install
...
INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] BUILD ERROR
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] One or more required plugin parameters are invalid/missing for 'build-helper:regex-property'

[0] Inside the definition for plugin 'build-helper-maven-plugin' specify the following:

<configuration>
  ...
  <value>VALUE</value>
</configuration>

-OR-

on the command line, specify: '-Dsomeversion=VALUE'
...
```

And just to make things complete, in case I'd use in my solution (currently commented out) `<regex>notmatched</regex>` as well as `<failIfNoMatch>true</failIfNoMatch>`:

```
mvn install -Dsomeversion=1.3
...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Unnamed - sample:sample:pom:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO]    task-segment: [install]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] [build-helper:regex-property {execution: regex-property}]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] No match to regex 'notmatched' found in '1.3'.
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
...
```

Please note, that last 2 errors differ - one is for missing property and the other one for the non-matching regexp.

So just to sum up, I believe that `build-helper-maven-plugin` works as expected.

Comment: Yes, I agree with you. I also concluded that I should use a profile including this plugin and it is getting activated only when the system property is present. There is no issue with failIfNoMatch. Regarding the other issue with the backslash, please see http://mojo.codehaus.org/build-helper-maven-plugin/usage.html. I concluded also not to use the backslash (as it is shown for some reason in the Usage webpage) as it is not working. Thank you very much

Comment: you're right regrading the backslash, I didn't notice initialy. I think there should be documentation bug filled for the plugin to prevent confusion for others, feel free to do so at: http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MBUILDHELPER

Comment: I concur with @Peter_Butkovich.  The goal works without it and not with it.  It seemed wrong the moment I saw it, as I could not figure out why the backslash was needed based on my knowledge of maven and regex.  The backslash is WRONG, but it's in the Codehaus documentation.  Since Codehaus is out of business I don't know who could change it., but it's wrong and has also infiltrated its way into several SO answers.

Comment: @SteveCohen, I've found also really difficult to follow [MojoHaus](http://www.mojohaus.org/)'s team documentation on [regex-property](http://www.mojohaus.org/build-helper-maven-plugin/regex-property-mojo.html). I've managed to solve my issue but such a simple plugin and yet kind of hard do configure. :/